# Why pandas column not converted to Int64?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
       'Doc':['Order','Order','Inv','Order','Order','Shp','Order', 'Order','Inv'],
       'Rep':[101,101,101,102,102,102,103,103,103]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


#df['concat']= (df['ID'].convert_dtypes(convert_string = True) + "1").convert_dtypes(convert_integer = True)

df['concat']= (df['ID'].astype(str) + "1").convert_dtypes(convert_integer = True)

print(df['concat'].dtype)
```

output:

```
string
```

Why `df['concat']` is not `Int64` and how to get it?

Comment: @Vishnudev That will not work with all kind of numeric concatenation. I need universal method of concatenation of numbers. Method above does concatenation part as I need it. But I need afterwords to convert string to `Int64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
>>> df['concat'] = df['ID'].astype(str).add('1').astype('int64')
0    11
1    21
2    31
3    41
4    51
5    61
6    71
7    81
8    91
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: That gives me `int32`, not `dtype: int64`

Comment: It gives `int64` for me. Updated answer, try now.

Comment: It was because of your system, use `sys.maxsize` to see the maximum size in bytes a python int can be. This will be gigabytes in 32 bits, and exabytes in 64 bits.

Comment: How can I change it? I have 64 bit system.

Comment: Didn't the above work? I don't know how to change maxsize or whether it can be changed. It should be another question.  @vasili111

Comment: Sorry I did not realize that you updated code. That works the way I need: `df['concat'] = df['ID'].astype(str).add('1').astype('int64').convert_dtypes(convert_integer = True)`. Thank you.